# Bulk delete categories at once

Tags: magento2, category

I am using magento 2.4.
I have lots of categories & subcategories.
Is their any way to delete all at once using MySQL script ?
I have tried external script but timeout occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Execute below query in your database or create custom script for it.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_datetime; 
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_decimal; 
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_int; 
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_text; 
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_varchar; 
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_product; 
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_product_index;

INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `parent_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `path`, `position`, `level`, `children_count`) VALUES ('1', '0', '0', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '1', '0', '0', '1'),
('2', '3', '1', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '1/2', '1', '1', '0');

INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_int` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES 
('1', '69', '0', '1', '1'),
('2', '46', '0', '2', '1'),
('3', '69', '0', '2', '1');

INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_varchar` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES 
('1', '45', '0', '1', 'Root Catalog'),
('2', '45', '0', '2', 'Default Category');

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

DELETE FROM url_rewrite WHERE entity_type = 'category';
```

If you are using enterprise edition.
follow [stack exchange link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103532/magento-2-how-to-delete-all-categories-at-once/252516#252516)

you should make sure that after truncate category data you should insert default category (root category data) in **catalog_category_entity**, **catalog_category_entity_decimal** and **catalog_category_entity_varchar** table.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_varchar`;
INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `parent_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `path`, `position`, `level`, `children_count`) VALUES
(1, 3,  0,  '2022-05-04 05:33:27',  '2022-05-04 05:33:27',  '1',    0,  0,  1),
(2, 3,  1,  '2022-05-04 05:33:27',  '2022-05-04 05:33:27',  '1/2',  1,  1,  0);
INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_int` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES
(1, 69, 0,  1,  1),
(2, 69, 0,  2,  1),
(3, 46, 0,  2,  1);
INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_varchar` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES
(1, 45, 0,  1,  'Root Catalog'),
(2, 52, 0,  2,  'PRODUCTS'),
(3, 45, 0,  2,  'Default Category');
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: This is not working at all.
This issue appeared after following this answer.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/355603/category-issue-after-deleting-records-from-table-magento-2

Comment: Did you execute re-indexing and cache:flush command ?

Comment: You had missing to insert root category data. Make sure with "catalog_category_entity" , "catalog_category_entity_int" and  "catalog_category_entity_varchar". table

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this by

```
<?php
...
use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

/**
 * Class CategoryDeletion
 * @package Project\Catalog
 */
class CategoryDeletion
{
    /** @var Registry $registry */
    private $registry;


    /** @var CategoryFactory $categoryFactory */
    protected $categoryFactory

    /**
     * Category Deletion constructor.
     * @param CategoryFactory      $categoryFactory      Category Factory
     * @param Registry             $registry             Magento Registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        CategoryFactory             $categoryFactory,
        Registry                    $registry
    ) {
        $this->categoryFactory      = $categoryFactory;
        $this->registry             = $registry;
    }


    /**
     * Remove categories tree
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function removeCategories()
    {
        $categories = $this->categoryFactory->create()->getCollection();

        $this->registry->register("isSecureArea", true);
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            if($category->getId() > 2) {
                $category->delete();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

you can pass your category id here, if($category->getId() == 2) //you catg id