# Category issue after deleting records from table magento 2

Tags: magento2, category

I have deleted all records from the "catalog_category_entity" table & then created new some new records manually.
Now when I save category then nothing happen.
[image]

Image for reference.
how to fix this issue with saving category ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento needs a root category, Please run the following query, and before running this query take backup of your current database.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index`;
 
INSERT  INTO `catalog_category_entity`(`entity_id`,`entity_type_id`,`attribute_set_id`,`parent_id`,`created_at`,`updated_at`,`path`,`POSITION`,`level`,`children_count`) VALUES (1,3,0,0,'0000-00-00 00:00:00','2009-02-20 00:25:34','1',1,0,1),(2,3,3,0,'2009-02-20 00:25:34','2009-02-20 00:25:34','1/2',1,1,0);
INSERT  INTO `catalog_category_entity_int`(`value_id`,`entity_type_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES (1,3,32,0,2,1),(2,3,32,1,2,1);
INSERT  INTO `catalog_category_entity_varchar`(`value_id`,`entity_type_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES (1,3,31,0,1,'Root Catalog'),(2,3,33,0,1,'root-catalog'),(3,3,31,0,2,'Default Category'),(4,3,39,0,2,'PRODUCTS'),(5,3,33,0,2,'default-category');

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Source : https://gist.github.com/michelbrito/822016

Comment: Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'entity_type_id' in 'field list'

I am using magenro 2.4.3 version.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you have missing root category data in your database. Truncate below tables and re-insert root category missing data.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_varchar`;
INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `parent_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `path`, `position`, `level`, `children_count`) VALUES
(1, 3,  0,  '2022-05-04 05:33:27',  '2022-05-04 05:33:27',  '1',    0,  0,  1),
(2, 3,  1,  '2022-05-04 05:33:27',  '2022-05-04 05:33:27',  '1/2',  1,  1,  0);
INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_int` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES
(1, 69, 0,  1,  1),
(2, 69, 0,  2,  1),
(3, 46, 0,  2,  1);
INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_varchar` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES
(1, 45, 0,  1,  'Root Catalog'),
(2, 52, 0,  2,  'PRODUCTS'),
(3, 45, 0,  2,  'Default Category');
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: After execute below insert query, clean flush and do re-indexing.